# Videogular - How do i get started with Videogular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-video, videogular

i'm beginner of HTML5. i want to use the videogular

My Questions:

- How do i get started with Videogular?
- How do i configure (or) implement in html page?
- Is any specification need to implement videogular?.

  i referred [Videogular API](https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular/wiki/Videogular%27s-API.)

still, am in blank.

Comment: start with the beginnings of HTML(5) and Javascript. Then go take a look at AngularJS and finally you can integrate Videogular in your AngularJS app. Good luck!

Comment: I would say that ^^ is not helpful.  Videogular instructions for install and getting started are sparse.  I'm 6 months into writing Angular apps and I have to say Videogular made me struggle.